# Unable to compile Spring Boot application with external library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that I am developing using the STS on Eclipse. I am attempting to incorporate into this application the Jackson libraries using Maven.

The dependencies in my project, as identified in my POM file, are below:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.5</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have been attempting to compile the code using

```
mvnw clean package
```

but I am getting compilation failures caused by the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

The library with that class is already declared in the POM file!

I am clearly missing something here. How do I get the compiler to include the Jackson jars intothe compilation sp that mvnw stops failing?

Comment: Remove the jackson dependencies as well as the `spring-web` dependency. Those are already part of the `spring-boot-starter-web`. Your jackson dependency is not compatible with the spring version you are using, hence the error. Removing them lets Spring Boot manage a compatible version. In addition to that you don't need the `spring-boot-starter` dependency as well (that is implied by the other starters already).

Comment: you only need `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-test` and remove the remaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look into the following url, jackson databind has dependencies on jackson core and jackson annotations. So there is no need to mention them. It will internally use the dependency. As Denium Sir said, remove the dependencies, use only jackson databind for normal case, in case of Spring boot application simply use BOM (Build of Material), there is no need to mention these dependencies.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.7.5